# Can the DynamoDB attributes be used on an F# record type?

Tags: f#, amazon-dynamodb

I'm converting some C# classes with the `DynamoDB` attributes like `DynamoDBTable` over to F#. Do these attributes work with F# record types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. If DynamoDB needs getters and setters, just add the [`CLIMutable`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-climutableattribute.html) attribute as well.

Comment: Finally had a chance to try this. Confirmed that the record types work great with DynamoDB. Added an alternative answer with a sample type decorated with the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternative answer to provide a simple code example.

```ml
[<CLIMutable>]
type Address = {
    AddressType: int
    AddressLine1: Nullable<string>
    AddressLine2: Nullable<string>
    City: string
    State: string
    Zip: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<DynamoDBTable("Customer")>]
type Customer =
    { [<DynamoDBHashKey>]
      Id: string

      [<DynamoDBProperty>]
      Name: string

      [<DynamoDBProperty>]
      Addresses: Address[] }
```

These F# record types worked perfectly saving to DynamoDB. One issue I ran into was that DynamoDB API would not take properties defined as F# options. The error actually says options are not supported so no doubts there.

Excerpt from the stack trace.

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Type Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] is unsupported, it cannot be instantiated
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.StorageConfig..ctor(ITypeInfo targetTypeInfo) in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\DynamoDBv2\Custom\DataModel\InternalModel.cs:line 331
```

For those fields I used the `Nullable` type instead and that cleared the error. `Option.toNullable` can be used to convert options to this type.

The `Address` type that is nested within the `Customer` did not require any DynamoDB attributes.